# What duration to request for a multiple-entry visa to Finland, from India?

Tags: visas, schengen, indian-citizens, multiple-entry, finland

I want to apply for multiple-entry visa, so what should be the duration of stay?

Currently I am planning for 10 days only so should it be 10 days or shall I give more than that, suppose 45 or 90 days?

And what should I mention in my cover letter as my sole intention is of tourism?

Also, for multiple entry do I need to have insurance of complete duration of one year for which I am applying or is it enough if I have insurance for the ten days of my first visit?

Comment: I do not intent several visit but I may visit again some time once if I have multiple entry visa that is the initial thought atleast.

As far as return is concerned I have a very good job in India and my complete family is in India and being the eldest child I need to take of them.

Please suggest accordingly.

Thanks

Answer (score 5):

Finland has one of the highest success rates for multiple-entry visas (about 80%).

If you envision multiple visits and you have a good premise to support multiple visits, then you should apply for a validity of 1 year and use the Schengen 90/180 rule to govern your actual visits.  This advice would be true even for your first application.

There is no risk in asking for a year. If they do not think you qualify for a year, they will downsize the validity to something they are comfortable with. If they grant you a year, then you have saved.

See the META thread: [Unanswered or dubious answers on Schengen visa questions](https://travel.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3703/unanswered-or-dubious-answers-on-schengen-visa-questions) for some background on this question. And remember that your premise is key-critical.

For your other questions...

> And what should I mention in my cover letter as my sole intention is
>   of tourism?

Get real. The overwhelming consensus is that you *tell them the truth*. Explain your intentions with natural language and use a translator if needs be to assure that it is clear and crisp.

> Also, for multiple entry do I need to have insurance of complete
>   duration of one year for which I am applying or is it enough if I have
>   insurance for the ten days of my first visit?

Get coverage for your initial visit. When the border officials see a multiple visit visa they may challenge you for insurance so be prepared for it.